# OutBoundEmail Setup in 2009

Tags: 2009, outbound-email

The Outbound Email option in TCM explorer under Email Publication is not coming. I am trying to set this up in Development environment. Also I need to create some address books using this. 
[image: OE]

Could you please suggest what is the problem? I checked the products is installed already, license is valid (as per the installation guide). I might be missing something which links this setup to CM. I am trying to find out as well, please help me with your ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found it, "Default sync Target" needs to be selected from "Audience Management" Tab. then it populates the Outbound Email option in the Publication. I am trying to set up the complete cycle, so will let you know if any help required again for this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order for a Publication to be considered an Audience Manager / Outbound E-mail Publication you need to fill in *something* on the "Audience Management" tab of the Publication.